# Make the arms of a PNG stickman move

Tags: modeling, 2d

I have a **PNG of a stickman**, and I'd like to **make** his **arms move**.

I thought I had to **reproduce the stickman on Blender** to only move some parts of him.

The problem is that **I'm unable to reproduce him well**, and I also **believe** there's a **more efficient way** to do that.

On the **right**, there's the **PNG of the stickman** imported on Blender. On the **left**, there's **my trial** to reproduce him.

[image]

Comment: so you probably need to make one piece instead of separating the arms, and create a series of small bones for the shoulder, or maybe a segmented bone?

Comment: @moonboots How can I create the shoulder? I'm struggling to reproduce that shape

Comment: The problem is how to model it so that it bends the way you want when you'll animate it. Maybe you should tell a bit more about how you want to animate it, what are the different poses etc? I wonder if the best would not to create some shapekeys

Comment: @moonboots I just want to move his arms, so that the stickman can say hello and hold something. Is that hard to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not easy to animate, first you should think carefuly about what different poses you need, for example if he's supposed to raise his arm, here is the kind of topology and armature you could create:

[image]

The arm bones have some *Copy Rotation* constraints, so you just need to rotate the first one and the other ones will follow:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to create all those shapes, could you please provide some extra information on how to do that or share the blender file? Thanks for helping :)

Comment: First you need to be extra precise about all the poses he is supposed to do, like a storyboard, it will help to find the best solution for your character

Comment: I want him to hold a fish can and to move his arms up and down as you showed in your answer (without the can). It would be great if he could bring the arms as up as possible. Is this precise enough?

Comment: Could you share with me the file that contains the arm shown in your answer? I still did not figure it out

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://blend-exchange.com/b/bqG4JrZ1

Comment: Thank you so much, the arm movement that you made possible is perfect. Could you give me some hints on how to create the other arm and add static legs head?

Comment: Blender Stack Exchange is for precise questions, for more broad request, maybe as on Blenderartists?

Comment: Also explain all the things that your character is supposed to do, with some drawings